# Self referencing constraints

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

In the process of familiarizing myself with the [or-tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization) library from google. I've been implementing some simple examples.
One exercise I set myself to do was to implement a sudoku solver.
It was relatively simple to implement:

- 81 integer variables
- all rows are different constraint
- all columns are different constraint
- all 3x3 regions are different constraint
- and some initial values on the board

After that I came across a [sudoku variant](https://sudokupad.app/qB6JNbFQqL) with some different rules and I tried to create a solver for this case but to no avail.
I'm having a hard time implementing the constraints for the following rule:

> When digit z is in cell (x, y) then digit y is in cell (x, z) and digit x is in cell (z, y)

I need to use the value of one of the cells in the sudoku board as one coordinate to another cell.

I have tried using the AddElement method:

```py
size=9
# build board
board=[]
for i in range(size):
   row=[]
   for j in range(size):
      row.append(model.NewIntVar(1, 9, f"{i},{j}"))
   board.append(row)

# when digit z is in cell (x,y) then digit y is in cell (x,z) and digit x is in cell (z,y)
flat_board = [col for row in board for col in row]
for x in range(size):
    for y in range(size):
       z = model.NewIntVar(0,8,f"z{x}{y}")
       model.Add(z == board[x][y]-1)
       model.AddElement(x*size+z,flat_board, y+1)
       model.AddElement(z*size+y,flat_board, x+1)
```

I get this error: TypeError: NotSupported: model.GetOrMakeIndex((9 * z00))

Is this even possible to implement?
If not AddElement, [which method](https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/python/sat/python/cp_model) should I use?

Note: I'm using the python wrapper

Comment: I don’t think your “board.append(row)” is at the correct indentation level.

Comment: @Mark Seagoe Thanks! Fixed the indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element constraint takes a variable for its index, not an arbitrary expression.

Comment: Thanks! So the solution was: instead of creating a variable with z value, create two variables with the final index value, one for each case.